# How to toggle between two menu items on click and close previous when next is toggled?

Tags: javascript, html

What am I trying to do. I have a menu navigation with 2 menu items the search and hamburger icon next to each other.

When I click on "MENU" the div will display the menu navigation items and will close when I click once again because of the toggle event.

However, when I open up "MENU" and switch back to "SEARCH" where, a different div should be displayed it messes up the logical structure between these two on toggle.

So, I want to toggle between SEARCH and MENU content no matter which one is selected / toggled. To close previous (remove class and add class to the next active element).

How can I do this?

**HTML:**

```html
<a href="#" class="search js-search">SEARCH</a>

<a href="#" class="hamburger js-hamburger">MENU</a>

<nav class="navigation js-navigation">
    <div class="content hidden">
        <input type="search" placeholder="search" />
    </div>

    <div class="content hidden">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**JS:**

```
(() => {
    const navigation = document.querySelector('.js-navigation');

    if(!navigation) {
        return;
    }

    const hamburger = document.querySelector('.js-hamburger');
    const search = document.querySelector('.js-search');

    let contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

    const onClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        contents.forEach((content) => {
            content.classList.remove('hidden');
            content.classList.add('hidden');
        })
    }


    hamburger.addEventListener('click', onClick);
    search.addEventListener('click', onClick);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldnt you add:

```
            if (content.classList.contains("hidden")) {

              content.classList.remove('hidden');
            } else {
              content.classList.add('hidden');
            }
```

Changeing classList didnt work for me, but this took effect:

```
<html>

<body>

<a href="#" class="search js-search" onClick="toggle('search');">SEARCH</a>

<a href="#" class="hamburger js-hamburger" onClick="toggle('menu');">MENU</a>

<nav class="navigation js-navigation">
    <div id="search" class="content">
        <input type="search" placeholder="search" />
    </div>

    <div id="menu" class="content">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<script>

function toggle(id) {
    var isHidden = document.getElementById(id).style.visibility == "hidden";
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = isHidden ? "visible" : "hidden";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also seems you could alternatively go with classList.toggle:

```
const navigation = document.querySelector('.js-navigation');

const hamburger = document.querySelector('.js-hamburger');
const search = document.querySelector('.js-search');

let contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

const onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    contents.forEach((content) => {
        content.classList.toggle('hidden');
    })
}


hamburger.addEventListener('click', onClick);
search.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

Comment: Is there any difference between .contains and .includes and will this toggle when one is clicked and so one?